# __PostBack from with a Growl Message

Tags: asp.net, c, updatepanel, postback

i'm trying to update my asp.net gridview from a close method of a Growl Message.

the jquery code is:

```
  $.gritter.add({
              title: 'Success',
              text: msg.d[0],
                                sticky: true,
                                after_close: function () {
                                    __doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '');
                                }
                            });
```

the gridview update panel is:

```
        <div class="module_content">

                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" />
                    <asp:GridView ID="grd1">
        <Columns> 
            <asp:TemplateField>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Hyperlink href="#" id="getSessionID" class="view-details" runat="server">View details</asp:Hyperlink>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>

             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Message Id">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("SessionID") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>           
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sender">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("Sender") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>                
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Message Date">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:HyperLink CssClass="msgDateDate" ID="lnkMsgDateSummary" Text='<%#DateTime.Parse(Eval("MsgDate").ToString()).ToShortDateString()%>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>                
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Message Type">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink CssClass="msgDateType" ID="lnkMsgDateType" Text='<%# Eval("MsgType")%>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>                
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reference">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <%# Eval("MsgRef")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> 
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <%# Eval("Status")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>                
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
      </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Within the gridview is a hyperlink, which opens up a dialog, the dialog calls a webmethod, which results in the data of the gridview changing.

I use a Growl notification to inform the end user that something has changed, and on click the ok button the after_close function is called.

When I debug the OnLoad=UpdatePanel1_Load is called, and I can see that all that changes are being bound etc.

However, my GridView total vanishes after the after_close method is run, it's not even in the DOM anymore.

Oddly though the label is there!

Can anyone tell me why my Grid vanishes?

****EDIT****

Ok, so i've added the EmptyDataText to the gridview, and the text specified in here is visible. So, even though a call the bindmethod my Gridview is empty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was user error. I had a case statment which was loading hte grids data based on date selected in a drop down, then drop down menu was empty, therefore my code was performing as expected, i/e no data to display you plonker :-)

Answer (score 0):

On your page load event, you need to implement a check when `ispostback` is true, then do not load the page to default value i.e. binding of grid view. 
Hope this helps.